# How to get ignored files with GiT

Tags: git

Hy everyone,
I'm trying to get all ignored files im Git, but I don't know how to do.
I already find some commands like `git status --ingored`
The result :
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Untracked files:
(use "git add ..." to include in what will be committed)

```
.DS_Store
ex00/.DS_Store
ex01/.DS_Store
ex01/.testShell00.swp
ex01/testShell00
ex02/test1
ex02/test3
ex02/test4
ex02/test5
ex02/test6
ex06/
test.txt
```

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)

But I just need files and I don't want others stuff

Thanks for your help
Have a good day

Comment: What is it that you are trying to do? If you want to ignore some files, you can add `.gitignore` file to control git tracking.

Comment: By get, do you want to list all ignored files? Or are you trying to ignore those files so it no longer tells you about certain untracked files?

Answer (score 0):

lists out all ignored files

```
git ls-files --others -i --exclude-standard
```

refer [docs](https://git-scm.com/docs) to know more about git

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I tried it, but got this :                                              warning: could not open directory '.DocumentRevisions-V100/': Permission denied
warning: could not open directory '.fseventsd/': Permission denied
warning: could not open directory '.TemporaryItems/': Permission denied                       I'm im school right now, it's may be because of that